# How is Cryogenic fuel kept... Cryogenic in rockets

Tags: falcon-9, fuel, design, cryogenics, lox

How is cryogenic fuel & oxidizer kept at cryogenic temperatures in rockets? I am mostly interested in the first stage of launch vehicles rather than something like a Centaur that keeps hydrolox cold for a long time. So how does something like a Falcon 9 first stage mitigate boil-off? Does one have an isolated tank that has a rate of boil-off that is slow enough that by the time the first stage has expended all of its fuel boil off isn't a concern or is there some complicated active glycol jacketing?

Comment: Boil off is kind of beneficial after lift off because it generates gas that fills the empty tank space left by the consumed fuel and equalizes tank pressure.

Answer (score 3):

[This answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/24591/how-do-rockets-keep-their-fuel-in-a-liquid-state) helps to explain it--you just accept the boiloff for the short time before the propellant is consumed, and Falcon 9 has to be fueled immediately before launch. But Saiboogu didn't really mention that cryogenic tanks are insulated. That's discussed a bit [here](https://forum.nasaspaceflight.com/index.php?topic=46730.0) in a NASA forum. Delta IV, Space Shuttle external tank, and Ariane V are examples. [Cork](https://amorimcorkcomposites.com/media/1095/brochure-aerospace_digital.pdf) is a popular material. It's more important for liquid hydrogen since that has such a low boiling point. I don't think the Atlas V liquid oxygen tank is insulated; at least I can't find anything that says it is.

Comment: there's more about "rocket cork" here: [Why would rocket bodies use specifically ablative coatings to reduce boil-off of cryogenic propellants? Is ablation important for this?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/35271/12102)